# Make one div define height of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a textarea that **onkeyup** expands with addition of content inside it. The textarea is inside a div as shown below:

```
<div id='sendMes' class='container-fluid'>
<form action='#' method='POST'>
    <textarea onkeyup='auto_grow(this)' id='textarea' cols='50' name='msg_body' placeholder='Type a message...'></textarea>
    <button id='post' type='submit' name='submit'><i class='fa fa-send'></i></button>
</form>
</div>
```

The function for the **onkeyup event** is as follows:

```
function auto_grow(element) {
    element.style.height = "5px";
    element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
```

The div **sendMes** as indicated on the html code is below another div with an ID of **messageThread** and its code is as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="messageThread">
</div>
```

So, as **sendMes** expands upwards it ends up covering the contents of the **messageThread** div. 
Kindly assist me in coming up with a javascript function that would reduce the height of **messageThread** as it increases the height of **sendMes** and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is Sass, where you can define variables and use them throughout your files: check this out http://sass-lang.com/guide

```
$change-height:    10px;

#sendMes {
  height: 10px + $change-height
}


#messageThread {
  height: 10px - $change-height
}
```